What is the upper bound on the error of estimating mutual information, when distributions are estimated by histogram density estimation methods
Consider the two 1D random variables  and . Their mutual information (MI) is defined as
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
  I(X;Y) &\stackrel{\mathrm{def}}{=} D_\mathrm{KL}(P_{(X,Y)}||P_{X}\otimes P_{Y})\
  &= \int_ X \int_Y p_{(X,Y)}(x, y) \log \frac{p_{(X,Y)}(x, y)}{p_{X}(x)p_{Y}(y)} \ \mathrm{d}x \ \mathrm{d}y\, \\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}
What is available to estimate this are data points $(\{(x_i, y_i)\}_{i=1}^{N}$ drawn iid from ((X, Y)) , which is our dataset.
Through discretization and binning we compute the histogram of the joint and marginal probabilities and afterward we can estimate MI using
$I(X;Y) = \sum_{x \in X} \sum_{y \in Y} p_{(X,Y)}(x, y) \log \frac{p_{(X,Y)}(x, y)}{p_{X}(x)p_{Y}(y)}\ $
I am interested in finding any possible upper bound on the error,  in these 2 cases.

bins are equidistance: I.e. the bin width is fixed
bins are equiprobable (equinumeric): I.e. we do the discretization as follow: we find the boundaries of the bins, both for X and Y, such that number of datapoints per every bin is K (a fixed number lets say 10). To make it clear, the joint probability will NOT be equinumeric in this setting (Just consider the whole thing as a logic for discretization and computing the histograms).

I want to find a bound on the error which includes N (number of samples) and in case of d-dimensional random variables also includes d.
Any formula that I can start with and adapt it for my problem is appreciated.
